# When to use Finished vs Over?

Tags: prepositions, idioms, questions, past-participles

Why do we always say:

> The class is over.
>
> The time is over.
>
> The time of class is over.

Why don't we say:

- The class is finished.

Comment: They're pretty much equivalent here. Note that it would be credible to say *Our time is **over** - but the lesson isn't **finished**, so please remain seated*. And it would be equally credible to say *Our time is **finished** - but the lesson isn't **over**, so please remain seated.*

Comment: I feel we need a bit more info here. Ambiguity remains. For example: you're dealing with the two words in far too specific a context. "The class **has** finished" sounds just as good as "the class is over" to me.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Don't know why, but I prefer your first sentence, as "over" means "exceed"

Comment: @Ahmad: Yes, I probably shouldn't have said *equally* credible. You're quite right that idiomatically, [*our time is **over***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=our+time+is+finished%2Cour+time+is+over&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cour%20time%20is%20over%3B%2Cc0) is far more common than ***finished***. But they're both "credible / valid".

Answer (score 1):

Because in your experience, folks tend to use *over* to refer to discrete portions of a class (each class day) and to use *finished* to refer to the class as a whole.

As Fumble and JMB have noted, it would be equally credible and proper to use the word **over** as it would to use the word **finished** and both words have definitions that denote *ended*; *completed*.

The only substantive difference between the two words is that in addition to noting the completion or ending of something, the word **over** can also mean *"throughout the duration of"* or *"while engaged in or occupied with"*. That's where you can end up with a sentence like this: *He'd been slaving at his job over the weekend and is still there, even though it's now Monday and the weekend is over.*

It may be for this reason that English speakers show a tendency to use **over** to refer to shorter durations or discrete elements, and **finished** for longer durations and entire collections, but that is entirely conjecture on my part.

Answer (score 0):

> The time is over

sounds more natural to me than *The class is over*,

According to the Longman dictionary, *over* is used for an event, an activity or period of time

> The summer was nearly over

To me, "over" means something like "exceed", time is always passing, but an event or period in time could be over (time exceed the period was assigned to it), while *finished* means there is not much remained of something

Answer (score 0):

The words are quite easily interchanged.  However, I have felt a slight preference to only use "finished" when the thing being discussed involved some sort of activity.  "Over" seems to be more applicable in any circumstance, but is more comfortably used for things that are not activities.

Thus we may say "Summer is over," or "My thesis is over," or "My thesis is finished," but it would be more unusual to see "Summer is finished," because a time period doesn't involve some activity.  If you see "Summer is finished," it means the same thing, but it may imply that the speaker felt Summer was doing something, and it completed doing that thing.  Likewise, if I were to say "My thesis is over," it means the same thing, but may imply that I felt the thesis was not completed, but some artificial time limit got in the way.

Most English speakers will not complain if the words are intermixed.  There are differences in emotional content between the words, but those are best grasped over time through use.